# Как обрабатывать команды OpenGL в цикле

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Пишу простую программу - точка ползёт по экрану.

Не понимаю, как написать цикл.
Написал такой код. Переменная X изменяется в цикле, и у точки меняются координаты.
Ошибки компилятора нет, но окно с точкой не выводится.
Может я с последовательностью команд что-то напутал?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
 
float X;
 
void display() 
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(8);
   
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex2f(X, X);   
 
        glEnd();
   
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
 
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    X = 0.1;
 
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080);
    glutCreateWindow("Проба");
      
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
 
    while (X < 1)
    {
        X = X + 0.01;
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Переменная X изменяется в цикле* - это в цикле из одной итерации с return 0 на конце? Ну и еще immediate mode OpenGL уже давно устарел.

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Убрал return 0, окно с точкой появилось, но точка не движется, стоит на месте в начале координат.

Comment: Вызов glutMainLoop, блокирует поток до тех пор, пока вы не закроете окно, теперь подумайте как это исправить

Comment: Заработало! На киберфоруме подсказали использовать glutTimerFunc

Я так понимаю, glutDisplayFunc - рисует примитивы и задает их параметры, которые можно менять.

glutTimerFunc - меняет параметры с определенной частотой.

glutPostRedisplay - меняет старый рисунок на новый.

glutMainLoop - запускает бесконечный цикл, в котором меняются картинки, а также обрабатываются события от мыши, клавы и меню (если есть). Выход из этой команды должен быть в менюшке, или ctrl+alt+del.

Comment: #include <glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
 
float X;
 
void display()
{
    if (X < 1) 
    {
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPointSize(8);
 
 
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 
            glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
 
            glVertex2f(X, X);
 
        glEnd();     
    }
    
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
 
 
void TimerFunction(int value) 
{
    X = X + 0.001;
    glutPostRedisplay();  // перерисовываем экран
    glutTimerFunc(33, TimerFunction, 1);  //запускаем таймер заново.
}

Comment: int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    X = 0;
 
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080);
    glutCreateWindow("Проба");
    
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
 
    glutTimerFunc(33, TimerFunction, 1);
 
    glutMainLoop();
    
    return 0;
}